# Show that $D_n$ is a subgroup of Perm($\mathbb{C}$).

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, complex-numbers

For $ n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $0 \le r <n$, define $f_r : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ ; $z \mapsto ze^{2\pi i r/n}$ and $c: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ ; $z \mapsto \bar{z}$.

a) Let $D_n = \{ f_0, ..., f_{n-1}, f_0 \circ c, ..., f_{n-1} \circ c \}$. Show that $D_n$ is a subgroup of Perm($\mathbb{C}$), where Perm($\mathbb{C}$) is the set of all invertible self-maps on $\mathbb{C}$.

b) Show $D_4$ is not isomorphic to $Q_8$.

Here's what I have so far:

First I said that $f_k \circ c (z) = f_k(\bar{z}) = \bar{z}e^{2\pi i k/n} = ze^{2 \pi i (n-k)/n} = f_{n-k}$, since taking the conjugate just reflects $x$ across the real axis.
So $f_k \circ c = f_{n-k}$ for any $k$.

To check closure, then, just consider two elements $f_k$ and $f_j$. Then $f_k \circ f_j = f_{k+j (mod n)}$.
For inversion, $f_y^{-1} = f_{n-y}$, so all inverses are in $D_n$.

Comment: The dihedral groups are usually not abelian, and $\mathbb C$ is abelian with respect to both addition and multiplication, so this is impossible.

Perhaps you mean that they are subgroups of the group of bijective functions on $\mathbb C$, under composition?

Comment: Multiplying by $e^{2\pi ir/n}$ adds $2\pi r/n$ to the phase of $z$. Use polar coordinates to see this. (This kind of fact is usually discussed quite early in any course on complex variables.) Now, what are you trying to show it's a subgroup of again? Clearly it's not a subgroup of $(\Bbb C,+)$ or $(\Bbb C,\times)$, so what operation are you thinking of having on $\Bbb C$ here?

Comment: @Nishant Yes, I'm using $\mathbb{C}!$ as the group of permutations, i.e. the set of all invertible self maps on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @anon, I'm using $\mathbb{C}!$ as the set of invertible self-maps on $\mathbb{C}$. Thanks, I've clarified the question now.

Comment: I would use $S_{\Bbb C}$ or ${\rm Perm}(\Bbb C)$ or any **standard** notation to denote the group of permutations of the set $\Bbb C$. Clearly your $D_n$ is a subset, you just need to show it's closed under composition and inverses. Did you try? If you don't know that multiplying by a modulus $1$ complex number is a rotation of the plane, then may I ask what kind of experience you have with complex numbers? Do you have any thoughts, work, ideas to show? Have you ever done any exercises where you have to prove a specific subset of a group is a subgroup before?

Comment: @anon I added my attempt at closure under composition and inversion. Is my thought process correct so far, or am I missing something?

Comment: You have shown how the $n$ rotations (which generate the cyclic subgroup $C_n \subset D_n$) form a subgroup of $\operatorname{Perm}(\Bbb{C})$.  What about composing reflections with rotations?  Reflections with reflections?  What about inverses of reflections?

Comment: By the way, there's a mistake in your calculation $f_k \circ c = f_{n - k}$.  It's not possible for a reflection to be a rotation:  the former switches orientation while the latter preserves orientation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**  the relation between rotations and reflections looks like this:
$$
(f_k \circ c) (z) = f_k(\bar{z}) = \bar{z}e^{2\pi i k/n} = c(ze^{2 \pi i (n-k)/n}) = (c \circ f_{n-k}) (z)
$$

Now you should *calculate each of the following expressions* (for $0 \le k < n$) and use the relation to express the result in the form $f_j$ or $f_j \circ c$ for some $j$ (these are the elements of the group that you provided).  You can use the relation at the level of functions $(f_k \circ c = c \circ f_{n - k})$, so you don't have to drag the argument $z$ through your calculation.

Closure under composition:

- $f_k \circ f_j$
- $f_k \circ (f_j \circ c)$
- $(f_k \circ c) \circ f_j$
- $(f_k \circ c) \circ (f_j \circ c)$

Closure under inverses:

- $f_k^{-1}$
- $(f_k \circ c)^{-1}$

Comment: Okay, so I have $f_k \circ f_j = f_{k+j}$, $f_k \circ (f_j \circ c) = f_{k+j} \circ c$, $(f_k \circ c) \circ c = f_k$, and $(f_k \circ c) \circ (f_j \circ c) = f_{k+j}$. So, all of these are in $D_n$. Then for inverses, $f_k^{-1} = f_{n-k}$ and $(f_k \circ c)^{-1} = (f_{n-k} \circ c)$, which are also in $D_n$. Yeah, that makes sense, if I did that correctly.

Comment: Just realized I wasn't entirely correct -> $(f_k \circ c) \circ (f_j \circ c) = f_{n-j+k}$. Also, $(f_k \circ c)^{-1} = (f_k \circ c)$.

Comment: Whoops.  In reading your first comment, I just noticed a typo in my answer.  The third expression to check closure for is a reflection composed with a rotation.  I will fix that.

Comment: Notice that every reflection is its own inverse and that the inverse of a rotation is a rotation "the rest of the way around".  Your geometric intuition should confirm these calculations.